# I m building an app using the react native with expo in which i need the permission for the image gallery on android

Tags: android, react-native, permissions, expo, camera-roll

As i mentioned above i m unable to get permissions for image gallery as according to the error i m getting it says CAMERA_ROLL is deprecated. I searched whole documentation regarding the same at react native website ass well as on expo documentation but i can't find anything helpful from those so it would be a big help if u can provide me the solutions. Also this is my first time here...sorry if the format is bad
[image: I have entered the screenshot of the code as you can see CAMERA_ROLL is strikethrough]

Comment: Please don't share your code as an image https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Use `ImagePicker.getCameraPermissionsAsync()` and `ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync()` for the camera

`ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync()` and `ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync()` for the gallery

Check the documentation here for other options:
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/

Comment: I have tried it but its still not working

Comment: There is no way to me to know why, may be you should try to recreate the example in the documentation.

Comment: ok thanks let me try...and also i think ImagePicker.getCameraPermissionsAsync() is used to get camera access but actually i just want permission to view photos from gallery

Comment: thanks for your support but i have tried this too but still the phone is not prompting the request for media permissions

Comment: view photos or let the user pick a photo? the former you can achieve using https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v44.0.0/sdk/media-library/ the latter using https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v44.0.0/sdk/imagepicker/#imagepickerlaunchimagelibraryasyncoptions (as mentioned before)